# On fitting a Poisson distribution to make sense of data

Tags: dataset, neural-network, sampling

Hi guys I am working with a regular network which has the shape of a square grid and contains `100x100=10000` nodes. The edges (links) between these nodes simply follow the shape of a chess table: each node which is not placed in the corner or along the boundary has 4 connections only, all of them involving its nearest neighbors. Accordingly, the nodes on the boundary have 3 connections only, while the nodes in the four corners have 2.

Now, this brings me to my problem. If you plot such data you will figure out you have 4 nodes with links=2, 98*4 nodes with links=3, and 10000-(98*4)-4 with links=4. This translates into three tuples to plot: `(x,y)=(2,4),(3,392),(4,9604)`. The resulting histogram is heavily skewed toward the right hand side:
 [image]

My question is: **what kind of distribution do you think would fit this dataset?** I was thinking of a Poisson distribution (the x-axis values are discrete and not continuous) skewed to the right. **I will appreciate any kind of help/guidance.** Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "make sense of"? What are you using the distribution for?

Comment: This distribution will be useful for describing the degree distribution (sorry for repeating myself) of a regular, 2D lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other graphs, the degree distribution is a function of N. Specifically, the number of nodes with k=2 is constant (4), the  number of nodes with k=3 grows linearly with the length of one side $4l-4$, while the number of nodes with k=4 grows exponentially with the length of a side, $l^2-4l-4$. In the large $l$ (or $N$) limit, the degree distribution is 4.

You can get the exact distribution by normalizing this piecewise defined function (divide by $l^2=N$).

Comment: This will only rescale (normalize) my sample histogram. My question was more like "what distribution could fit this very dataset, based on the histogram shape?". Based on the shape of this histogram I am not able to recall a distribution with which to fit the data and try to give them an analytical interpretation.

Comment: Got it. Would you mind elaborating on your desired analytical properties? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do with the distribution.

Comment: This is part of a task concerning the analysis of some specific kinds of networks (regular, random, scale-free, etc.). For the random and scale-free cases we have some pretty analytical models that describe their distribution (the degree distribution is a Poisson distribution for a random network, while the scale-free network follows a power law distribution). For the regular network I failed to find something, so I decided to work this out myself by building one and plotting its histogram. But now I am stuck at that precise question I re-formulated before...

Comment: So, the properties I am after are simply those of an analytical curve, provided it exists, that fits these data.

Comment: Hi @Francesco, I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: So, to come to a conclusion, would you agree with the following? There is no single distribution which can fit these data, as a stepwise one, made of three different distributions, is needed. And if you agree, what would these three distributions be called?

Comment: I would say that the distribution is a piecewise defined function of N. There is nothing wrong with piecewise distributions. See for example the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).

Comment: Got it. It really sounds nice. Thanks. I often times know the tools but fail to give them a proper name. I should really look for a thorough statistics MOOC. Anything to suggest?

Comment: I learned stats in a traditional academic environment, so I don't know much about moocs. I have heard good things about [Think Stats](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkstats/) if you are already familiar with coding. Good luck! :)